# NFC request response android

Tags: android, request, response, nfc, transfer

I am developing one android application for transfering a file over NFC. I have 2 tabs in my application

1. files
2. requests

I do not know how to get request and response from NFC. Suppose I send any file from my files tab ListView to another device then it means I send request to that device and the file which I send should be saved in application's request folder of other user. If they click on that file from request then add that file in the device SD card.

Comment: You do not think you are asking too much?

Comment: ya i know but i just want to know that there is any way from which we know that we receive request from other device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below link might help you where he has explained how to transfer files b/w 2 android devices...

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sharing-files-with-nfc-on-android--cms-22501